# no connection to database as from php connect page

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-hosting

I keep getting a connection error when trying to connect to my database. 
I am on a shared host for my webpages.
I started by creating a database: ('herman' being replaced by the prefix added by my host)

```
Username = herman_tst
Password =test
Name = herman_tst
```

I can get into it via phpmyadmin without any problem as I imported some tables into it (not containing any user parameters)
I uploaded my .php files like the index.php etc
I updated my dbConnect.php file that makes the database connection (I believe) accordingly ('herman' being replaced by the prefix added by my host)

```
$dbUsername = "herman_tst";
$dbPassword = „test”;
$dbName = "herman_tst";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbName",
                $dbUsername,
                $dbPassword);

  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  print 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Still my browser respond that access to the database is denied:

> Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'deb41858_tst'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Fatal error: Call to
>   a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /home/deb41858/domains/doordelens.be/public_html/php/index.php on line
>   16

Cn anyone please indicate what I am missing here ?

Comment: Whats up with this `$dbPassword = „test”;` ?

Comment: it should be `$dbpassword="test";`

Comment: You code is trying to connect with `user 'deb41858_tst'@'localhost' `, not the username that you defined

Comment: Thx Guys, problem solved ... don't know what changed the "test" to „test” but re-changed it and now all is ok ;)
@John: indeed, but in my post here above I did not want to give away too much of my real account details (never know if someone is watching with bad intentions) but than again ... i should have adapted the error code also with the same dummies as in my problem description ;)